# Programming Sudoku in python

Tags: python, sudoku

```
import turtle

strelica = turtle.getturtle()
turtle.setup(800, 600)
prozor = turtle.Screen()
prozor.title("SUDOKU")
strelica.speed(0)


def kvadrat(a):    # a je duzina stranice
    strelica.pendown()
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)


def kucica(x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 40)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 80)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.pensize(3)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.pensize(0)


def unos(unos, x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.write(unos, font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))


kucica(-200, -200)
kucica(-80, -200)
kucica(40, -200)
kucica(-200, -80)
kucica(-80, -80)
kucica(40, -80)
kucica(-200, 40)
kucica(-80, 40)
kucica(40, 40)

unos("A", -190, 175)
unos("B", -150, 175)
unos("C", -110, 175)
unos("D", -70, 175)
unos("E", -30, 175)
unos("F", 10, 175)
unos("G", 50, 175)
unos("H", 90, 175)
unos("I", 130, 175)

unos("9", -215, -190)
unos("8", -215, -150)
unos("7", -215, -110)
unos("6", -215, -70)
unos("5", -215, -30)
unos("4", -215, 10)
unos("3", -215, 50)
unos("2", -215, 90)
unos("1", -215, 130)

unos("5", -190, 130)
unos("3", -150, 130)
unos("7", -30, 130)
unos("6", -190, 90)
unos("1", -70, 90)
unos("9", -30, 90)
unos("5", 10, 90)
unos("9", -150, 50)
unos("8", -110, 50)
unos("6", 90, 50)
unos("8", -190, 10)
unos("6", -30, 10)
unos("3", 130, 10)
unos("4", -190, -30)
unos("8", -70, -30)
unos("3", 10, -30)
unos("1", 130, -30)
unos("7", -190, -70)
unos("2", -30, -70)
unos("6", 130, -70)
unos("6", -150, -110)
unos("2", 50, -110)
unos("8", 90, -110)
unos("4", -70, -150)
unos("1", -30, -150)
unos("9", 10, -150)
unos("5", 130, -150)
unos("8", -30, -190)
unos("7", 90, -190)
unos("9", 130, -190)

A = [5, 6, 8, 4, 7]
B = [3, 9, 6]
C = [8]
D = [1, 8, 4]
E = [7, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8]
F = [5, 3, 9]
G = [2]
H = [6, 8, 7]
I = [3, 1, 6, 5, 9]

red1 = [5, 3, 7]
red2 = [6, 1, 9, 5]
red3 = [9, 8, 6]
red4 = [8, 6, 3]
red5 = [4, 8, 3, 1]
red6 = [7, 2, 6]
red7 = [6, 2, 8]
red8 = [4, 1, 9, 5]
red9 = [8, 7, 9]

kucica1 = [5, 3, 6, 9, 8]
kucica2 = [7, 1, 9, 5]
kucica3 = [6]
kucica4 = [8, 4, 7]
kucica5 = [6, 8, 3, 2]
kucica6 = [3, 1, 6]
kucica7 = [6]
kucica8 = [4, 1, 9, 8]
kucica9 = [2, 8, 5, 7, 9]

a = len(A)
b = len(B)
c = len(C)
d = len(D)
e = len(E)
f = len(F)
g = len(G)
h = len(H)
i = len(I)

while (a != 9) or (b != 9) or (c != 9) or (d != 9) or (e != 9) or (f != 9) or (g != 9) or (h != 9) or (i != 9):
    kolona = input("Unesite zeljenu kolonu od A do I: ")
    red = int(input("Unesite zeljeni red od 1 do 9: "))
    broj = int(input("Koji broj zelite unijeti? "))

    if (kolona == "A") or (kolona == "a"):
        if broj in A:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -190
            A.append(broj)
            a += 1
    elif (kolona == "B") or (kolona == "b"):
        if broj in B:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -150
            B.append(broj)
            b += 1
    elif (kolona == "C") or (kolona == "c"):
        if broj in C:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -110
            C.append(broj)
            c += 1
    elif (kolona == "D") or (kolona == "d"):
        if broj in D:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -70
            D.append(broj)
            d += 1
    elif (kolona == "E") or (kolona == "e"):
        if broj in E:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -30
            E.append(broj)
            e += 1
    elif (kolona == "F") or (kolona == "f"):
        if broj in F:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 10
            F.append(broj)
            f += 1
    elif (kolona == "G") or (kolona == "g"):
        if broj in G:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 50
            G.append(broj)
            g += 1
    elif (kolona == "H") or (kolona == "h"):
        if broj in H:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 90
            H.append(broj)
            h += 1
    elif (kolona == "I") or (kolona == "i"):
        if broj in I:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 130
            I.append(broj)
            i += 1

    if red == 1:
        if broj in red1:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = 130
            red1.append(broj)
    elif red == 2:
        if broj in red2:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = 90
            red2.append(broj)
    elif red == 3:
        if broj in red3:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = 50
            red3.append(broj)
    elif red == 4:
        if broj in red4:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = 10
            red4.append(broj)
    elif red == 5:
        if broj in red5:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = -30
            red5.append(broj)
    elif red == 6:
        if broj in red6:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = -70
            red6.append(broj)
    elif red == 7:
        if broj in red7:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = -110
            red7.append(broj)
    elif red == 8:
        if broj in red8:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = -150
            red8.append(broj)
    elif red == 9:
        if broj in red9:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
        else:
            y = -190
            red9.append(broj)

    if kolona == "A" or kolona == "a" or kolona == "B" or kolona == "b" or kolona == "C" or kolona == "c":
        if red in [1, 2, 3]:
            if broj in kucica1:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica1.append(broj)
        elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
            if broj in kucica4:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica4.append(broj)
        elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
            if broj in kucica7:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica7.append(broj)
    if kolona == "D" or kolona == "d" or kolona == "E" or kolona == "e" or kolona == "F" or kolona == "f":
        if red in [1, 2, 3]:
            if broj in kucica2:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica2.append(broj)
        elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
            if broj in kucica5:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica5.append(broj)
        elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
            if broj in kucica8:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica8.append(broj)
    if kolona == "G" or kolona == "g" or kolona == "H" or kolona == "h" or kolona == "I" or kolona == "i":
        if red in [1, 2, 3]:
            if broj in kucica3:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica3.append(broj)
        elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
            if broj in kucica6:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica6.append(broj)
        elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
            if broj in kucica9:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
            else:
                kucica9.append(broj)

    unos(broj, x, y)

strelica.setposition(-200, 200)
strelica.write("KRAJ IGRE!", font=("Arial", 32, "bold"))

turtle.exitonclick()
```

hi guys, I am new in programminG and I have this project for my school. I have to  make Sudoku in python and this is what I have done, but it is not finished and it has some mistakes, e.g. if it appends one column and then it realises that this number is already in the rove I don't know how to delete it from the column.
PLEASE HELP

Comment: This is a good example of how [copy-and-paste-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) ruins your own code. Don't do it!

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem you need to add variable which will tell you if number was found in column so there is no need to check is number in row or in box.

So to fix that your code should look like this:

```
import turtle

strelica = turtle.getturtle()
turtle.setup(800, 600)
prozor = turtle.Screen()
prozor.title("SUDOKU")
strelica.speed(0)


def kvadrat(a):    # a je duzina stranice
    strelica.pendown()
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)


def kucica(x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 40)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 80)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.pensize(3)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.pensize(0)


def unos(unos, x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.write(unos, font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))


kucica(-200, -200)
kucica(-80, -200)
kucica(40, -200)
kucica(-200, -80)
kucica(-80, -80)
kucica(40, -80)
kucica(-200, 40)
kucica(-80, 40)
kucica(40, 40)


unos("A", -190, 175)
unos("B", -150, 175)
unos("C", -110, 175)
unos("D", -70, 175)
unos("E", -30, 175)
unos("F", 10, 175)
unos("G", 50, 175)
unos("H", 90, 175)
unos("I", 130, 175)

unos("9", -215, -190)
unos("8", -215, -150)
unos("7", -215, -110)
unos("6", -215, -70)
unos("5", -215, -30)
unos("4", -215, 10)
unos("3", -215, 50)
unos("2", -215, 90)
unos("1", -215, 130)

unos("5", -190, 130)
unos("3", -150, 130)
unos("7", -30, 130)
unos("6", -190, 90)
unos("1", -70, 90)
unos("9", -30, 90)
unos("5", 10, 90)
unos("9", -150, 50)
unos("8", -110, 50)
unos("6", 90, 50)
unos("8", -190, 10)
unos("6", -30, 10)
unos("3", 130, 10)
unos("4", -190, -30)
unos("8", -70, -30)
unos("3", 10, -30)
unos("1", 130, -30)
unos("7", -190, -70)
unos("2", -30, -70)
unos("6", 130, -70)
unos("6", -150, -110)
unos("2", 50, -110)
unos("8", 90, -110)
unos("4", -70, -150)
unos("1", -30, -150)
unos("9", 10, -150)
unos("5", 130, -150)
unos("8", -30, -190)
unos("7", 90, -190)
unos("9", 130, -190)

A = [5, 6, 8, 4, 7]
B = [3, 9, 6]
C = [8]
D = [1, 8, 4]
E = [7, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8]
F = [5, 3, 9]
G = [2]
H = [6, 8, 7]
I = [3, 1, 6, 5, 9]

red1 = [5, 3, 7]
red2 = [6, 1, 9, 5]
red3 = [9, 8, 6]
red4 = [8, 6, 3]
red5 = [4, 8, 3, 1]
red6 = [7, 2, 6]
red7 = [6, 2, 8]
red8 = [4, 1, 9, 5]
red9 = [8, 7, 9]

kucica1 = [5, 3, 6, 9, 8]
kucica2 = [7, 1, 9, 5]
kucica3 = [6]
kucica4 = [8, 4, 7]
kucica5 = [6, 8, 3, 2]
kucica6 = [3, 1, 6]
kucica7 = [6]
kucica8 = [4, 1, 9, 8]
kucica9 = [2, 8, 5, 7, 9]

a = len(A)
b = len(B)
c = len(C)
d = len(D)
e = len(E)
f = len(F)
g = len(G)
h = len(H)
i = len(I)

while (a != 9) or (b != 9) or (c != 9) or (d != 9) or (e != 9) or (f != 9) or (g != 9) or (h != 9) or (i != 9):
    kolona = input("Unesite zeljenu kolonu od A do I: ")
    red = int(input("Unesite zeljeni red od 1 do 9: "))
    broj = int(input("Koji broj zelite unijeti? "))
    error = False

    if (kolona == "A") or (kolona == "a"):
        if broj in A:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = -190
            A.append(broj)
            a += 1
    elif (kolona == "B") or (kolona == "b"):
        if broj in B:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = -150
            B.append(broj)
            b += 1
    elif (kolona == "C") or (kolona == "c"):
        if broj in C:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = -110
            C.append(broj)
            c += 1
    elif (kolona == "D") or (kolona == "d"):
        if broj in D:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = -70
            D.append(broj)
            d += 1
    elif (kolona == "E") or (kolona == "e"):
        if broj in E:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = -30
            E.append(broj)
            e += 1
    elif (kolona == "F") or (kolona == "f"):
        if broj in F:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = 10
            F.append(broj)
            f += 1
    elif (kolona == "G") or (kolona == "g"):
        if broj in G:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = 50
            G.append(broj)
            g += 1
    elif (kolona == "H") or (kolona == "h"):
        if broj in H:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = 90
            H.append(broj)
            h += 1
    elif (kolona == "I") or (kolona == "i"):
        if broj in I:
            print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
            error = True
        else:
            x = 130
            I.append(broj)
            i += 1

    if error == False:
        if red == 1:
            if broj in red1:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = 130
                red1.append(broj)
        elif red == 2:
            if broj in red2:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = 90
                red2.append(broj)
        elif red == 3:
            if broj in red3:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = 50
                red3.append(broj)
        elif red == 4:
            if broj in red4:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = 10
                red4.append(broj)
        elif red == 5:
            if broj in red5:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = -30
                red5.append(broj)
        elif red == 6:
            if broj in red6:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = -70
                red6.append(broj)
        elif red == 7:
            if broj in red7:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = -110
                red7.append(broj)
        elif red == 8:
            if broj in red8:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = -150
                red8.append(broj)
        elif red == 9:
            if broj in red9:
                print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
                error = True
            else:
                y = -190
                red9.append(broj)

    if error == False:
        if kolona == "A" or kolona == "a" or kolona == "B" or kolona == "b" or kolona == "C" or kolona == "c":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica1:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica1.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica4:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica4.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica7:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica7.append(broj)
        if kolona == "D" or kolona == "d" or kolona == "E" or kolona == "e" or kolona == "F" or kolona == "f":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica2:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica2.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica5:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica5.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica8:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica8.append(broj)
        if kolona == "G" or kolona == "g" or kolona == "H" or kolona == "h" or kolona == "I" or kolona == "i":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica3:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica3.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica6:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica6.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica9:
                    print("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                    error = True
                else:
                    kucica9.append(broj)

    if error == False:
        unos(broj, x, y)

strelica.setposition(-200, 200)
strelica.write("KRAJ IGRE!", font=("Arial", 32, "bold"))

turtle.exitonclick()
```

so if variable `error` is `True` then you don't call function `unos`.

To make code more readable (by the way your code is not easy to read, and lot of it should be shortened by using for loops and functions) you should use function to print error message and return `True`, it should be something like this:

```
def print_error(error_message):
    print(error_message)
    return True
```

and entire code would be:

```
import turtle

strelica = turtle.getturtle()
turtle.setup(800, 600)
prozor = turtle.Screen()
prozor.title("SUDOKU")
strelica.speed(0)


def kvadrat(a):    # a je duzina stranice
    strelica.pendown()
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)
    strelica.forward(a)
    strelica.left(90)


def kucica(x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 40)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 40)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y + 80)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 40, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.setposition(x + 80, y + 80)
    kvadrat(40)
    strelica.pensize(3)
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.pendown()
    kvadrat(120)
    strelica.pensize(0)


def unos(unos, x, y):
    strelica.penup()
    strelica.setposition(x, y)
    strelica.write(unos, font=("Arial", 16, "normal"))


def print_error(error_message):
    print(error_message)
    return True


kucica(-200, -200)
kucica(-80, -200)
kucica(40, -200)
kucica(-200, -80)
kucica(-80, -80)
kucica(40, -80)
kucica(-200, 40)
kucica(-80, 40)
kucica(40, 40)


unos("A", -190, 175)
unos("B", -150, 175)
unos("C", -110, 175)
unos("D", -70, 175)
unos("E", -30, 175)
unos("F", 10, 175)
unos("G", 50, 175)
unos("H", 90, 175)
unos("I", 130, 175)

unos("9", -215, -190)
unos("8", -215, -150)
unos("7", -215, -110)
unos("6", -215, -70)
unos("5", -215, -30)
unos("4", -215, 10)
unos("3", -215, 50)
unos("2", -215, 90)
unos("1", -215, 130)

unos("5", -190, 130)
unos("3", -150, 130)
unos("7", -30, 130)
unos("6", -190, 90)
unos("1", -70, 90)
unos("9", -30, 90)
unos("5", 10, 90)
unos("9", -150, 50)
unos("8", -110, 50)
unos("6", 90, 50)
unos("8", -190, 10)
unos("6", -30, 10)
unos("3", 130, 10)
unos("4", -190, -30)
unos("8", -70, -30)
unos("3", 10, -30)
unos("1", 130, -30)
unos("7", -190, -70)
unos("2", -30, -70)
unos("6", 130, -70)
unos("6", -150, -110)
unos("2", 50, -110)
unos("8", 90, -110)
unos("4", -70, -150)
unos("1", -30, -150)
unos("9", 10, -150)
unos("5", 130, -150)
unos("8", -30, -190)
unos("7", 90, -190)
unos("9", 130, -190)

A = [5, 6, 8, 4, 7]
B = [3, 9, 6]
C = [8]
D = [1, 8, 4]
E = [7, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8]
F = [5, 3, 9]
G = [2]
H = [6, 8, 7]
I = [3, 1, 6, 5, 9]

red1 = [5, 3, 7]
red2 = [6, 1, 9, 5]
red3 = [9, 8, 6]
red4 = [8, 6, 3]
red5 = [4, 8, 3, 1]
red6 = [7, 2, 6]
red7 = [6, 2, 8]
red8 = [4, 1, 9, 5]
red9 = [8, 7, 9]

kucica1 = [5, 3, 6, 9, 8]
kucica2 = [7, 1, 9, 5]
kucica3 = [6]
kucica4 = [8, 4, 7]
kucica5 = [6, 8, 3, 2]
kucica6 = [3, 1, 6]
kucica7 = [6]
kucica8 = [4, 1, 9, 8]
kucica9 = [2, 8, 5, 7, 9]

a = len(A)
b = len(B)
c = len(C)
d = len(D)
e = len(E)
f = len(F)
g = len(G)
h = len(H)
i = len(I)


while (a != 9) or (b != 9) or (c != 9) or (d != 9) or (e != 9) or (f != 9) or (g != 9) or (h != 9) or (i != 9):
    kolona = input("Unesite zeljenu kolonu od A do I: ")
    red = int(input("Unesite zeljeni red od 1 do 9: "))
    broj = int(input("Koji broj zelite unijeti? "))
    error = False

    if (kolona == "A") or (kolona == "a"):
        if broj in A:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -190
            A.append(broj)
            a += 1
    elif (kolona == "B") or (kolona == "b"):
        if broj in B:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -150
            B.append(broj)
            b += 1
    elif (kolona == "C") or (kolona == "c"):
        if broj in C:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -110
            C.append(broj)
            c += 1
    elif (kolona == "D") or (kolona == "d"):
        if broj in D:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -70
            D.append(broj)
            d += 1
    elif (kolona == "E") or (kolona == "e"):
        if broj in E:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = -30
            E.append(broj)
            e += 1
    elif (kolona == "F") or (kolona == "f"):
        if broj in F:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 10
            F.append(broj)
            f += 1
    elif (kolona == "G") or (kolona == "g"):
        if broj in G:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 50
            G.append(broj)
            g += 1
    elif (kolona == "H") or (kolona == "h"):
        if broj in H:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 90
            H.append(broj)
            h += 1
    elif (kolona == "I") or (kolona == "i"):
        if broj in I:
            error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
        else:
            x = 130
            I.append(broj)
            i += 1

    if error == False:
        if red == 1:
            if broj in red1:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = 130
                red1.append(broj)
        elif red == 2:
            if broj in red2:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = 90
                red2.append(broj)
        elif red == 3:
            if broj in red3:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = 50
                red3.append(broj)
        elif red == 4:
            if broj in red4:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = 10
                red4.append(broj)
        elif red == 5:
            if broj in red5:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = -30
                red5.append(broj)
        elif red == 6:
            if broj in red6:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = -70
                red6.append(broj)
        elif red == 7:
            if broj in red7:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = -110
                red7.append(broj)
        elif red == 8:
            if broj in red8:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = -150
                red8.append(broj)
        elif red == 9:
            if broj in red9:
                error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datom redu!")
            else:
                y = -190
                red9.append(broj)

    if error == False:
        if kolona == "A" or kolona == "a" or kolona == "B" or kolona == "b" or kolona == "C" or kolona == "c":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica1:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica1.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica4:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica4.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica7:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica7.append(broj)
        if kolona == "D" or kolona == "d" or kolona == "E" or kolona == "e" or kolona == "F" or kolona == "f":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica2:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica2.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica5:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica5.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica8:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica8.append(broj)
        if kolona == "G" or kolona == "g" or kolona == "H" or kolona == "h" or kolona == "I" or kolona == "i":
            if red in [1, 2, 3]:
                if broj in kucica3:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica3.append(broj)
            elif red in [4, 5, 6]:
                if broj in kucica6:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica6.append(broj)
            elif red in [7, 8, 9]:
                if broj in kucica9:
                    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj kucici!")
                else:
                    kucica9.append(broj)

    if error == False:
        unos(broj, x, y)

strelica.setposition(-200, 200)
strelica.write("KRAJ IGRE!", font=("Arial", 32, "bold"))

turtle.exitonclick()
```

code still isn't pretty, but that's problem in your programming you should use for loops (your variables where you store informations about rows, columns and boxes should be in list and then you should check if inputted number exists in row by using for loop and one if, and not by using nine ifs:
for example instead of using:

```
A = [5, 6, 8, 4, 7]
B = [3, 9, 6]
C = [8]
D = [1, 8, 4]
E = [7, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8]
F = [5, 3, 9]
G = [2]
H = [6, 8, 7]
I = [3, 1, 6, 5, 9]
```

you should use:

```
columns = [[5, 6, 8, 4, 7], [3, 9, 6], [8], [1, 8, 4], [7, 9, 6, 2, 1, 8], [5, 3, 9], [2], [6, 8, 7], [3, 1, 6, 5, 9]]
```

and then when you are checking if inputted number is already in column instead of using:

```
if (kolona == "A") or (kolona == "a"):
    if broj in A:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = -190
        A.append(broj)
        a += 1
elif (kolona == "B") or (kolona == "b"):
    if broj in B:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = -150
        B.append(broj)
        b += 1
elif (kolona == "C") or (kolona == "c"):
    if broj in C:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = -110
        C.append(broj)
        c += 1
elif (kolona == "D") or (kolona == "d"):
    if broj in D:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = -70
        D.append(broj)
        d += 1
elif (kolona == "E") or (kolona == "e"):
    if broj in E:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = -30
        E.append(broj)
        e += 1
elif (kolona == "F") or (kolona == "f"):
    if broj in F:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = 10
        F.append(broj)
        f += 1
elif (kolona == "G") or (kolona == "g"):
    if broj in G:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = 50
        G.append(broj)
        g += 1
elif (kolona == "H") or (kolona == "h"):
    if broj in H:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = 90
        H.append(broj)
        h += 1
elif (kolona == "I") or (kolona == "i"):
    if broj in I:
        error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
    else:
        x = 130
        I.append(broj)
        i += 1
```

you should use:

```
i = ord(kolona.upper())-65  # upper() makes Capital Letters more at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm
                            # ord() gives Unicode code of character more at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord
                            # -65 is used to make 65 in 0, 66 in 1 and so on
                        # idea is to get number 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B' 3 for 'D' and so on
if broj in columns[i]:
    error = print_error("Greska: Broj vec postoji u datoj koloni!")
else:
    x = -190
    columns[i].append(broj)
    a += 1
```

similar logics  applies to rows and boxes, if you want to improve your code you should do something like that.)

Also your sudoku program have other problems like: you can input number on place where number already exists, you can't delete inputted number...

PS: if you are going to use any of my code I suggest you to rename variables because your code isn't in english.